# WCF multiple endpoints each with their own username / password

Tags: wcf

Is it possible to create multiple endpoints which will be authenticated with their own username / password? (each endpoint with it's own credentials)

I have example for one endpoint and works fine. I don't know how to add several endpoints with same authentication methods.

My example:

```
String adress1 = "http://localhost/CalculatorService";
        String adress2 = "http://localhost/CalculatorService/en1/";
        Uri[] baseAddresses = { new Uri(adress1) };

        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), baseAddresses);
        ContractDescription contDesc = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(ICalculator));

        ServiceCredentials cd = new ServiceCredentials();
        cd.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
        cd.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = new CustomUserNameValidator();

        BasicHttpBinding b1 = new BasicHttpBinding();
        b1.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
        b1.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;

        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        smb.HttpGetUrl = new Uri(adress1);

        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(cd);
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

        EndpointAddress adr1 = new EndpointAddress(baseAddresses[0]);

        ServiceEndpoint en1 = new ServiceEndpoint(contDesc);
        en1.Binding = b1;
        en1.Address = adr1;
        en1.Name = "en1";


        ServiceEndpoint en2 = new ServiceEndpoint(contDesc);
        en2.Binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        en2.Address = new EndpointAddress(adress2);
        en2.Name = "en2";

        host.AddServiceEndpoint(en1);
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(en2);

        host.Open();
```

Authentication class:

```
class CustomUserNameValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
  {
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
      if (userName.ToLower() != "test" || password.ToLower() != "test")
      {
        throw new SecurityTokenException("Unknown Username or Incorrect Password");
      }
    }
  }
```

Interface / class:

```
[ServiceContract]
  public interface ICalculator
  {
    [OperationContract]
    double Add(double n1, double n2);
    [OperationContract]
    double Subtract(double n1, double n2);
    [OperationContract]
    double Multiply(double n1, double n2);
    [OperationContract]
    double Divide(double n1, double n2);
  }


  public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
  {
    public double Add(double n1, double n2)
    {
      return n1 + n2;
    }
    public double Subtract(double n1, double n2)
    {
      return n1 - n2;
    }
    public double Multiply(double n1, double n2)
    {
      return n1 * n2;
    }
    public double Divide(double n1, double n2)
    {
      return n1 / n2;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364606/wcf-different-authentication-method-for-each-endpoint). According to my knowledge this is not possible in WCF, because you authenticate access to service, not to particular endpoints.